# How do I add a constraint with a where clause in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with reservations. A reservation is made of a date range, and a time range. They also belong to a couple of other models. I would like to add a constraint that makes it impossible for a reservation to happen for overlapping times.

I have this:

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
    id integer NOT NULL,    
    dates daterange,
    times timerange,
    desk_id integer NOT NULL,
    space_id integer,
);

ALTER TABLE reservations ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (dates WITH &&, times WITH &&)
```

It works well. But I want this constraint to be scoped to desk_id and client_id.

It should be possible to save a record for overlapping times/dates when this record is about different desk_id or space_id.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just can use the exact same mechanism you were using, but also adding `desk_id` and `space_id` to your exclusions. This time, instead of using the `&&` operator (meaning overlaps) with the `=` operator:

```
ALTER TABLE reservations 
    ADD EXCLUDE 
    USING gist (desk_id WITH =, space_id WITH =, dates WITH &&, times WITH &&) ;
```

Theses inserts will work, because they involve two different `desk_id`:

```
INSERT INTO 
    reservations 
    (id, dates, times, desk_id, space_id)
VALUES 
   (1, '[20170101,20170101]'::daterange, '[10:00,11:00]'::timerange, 10, 10),
   (2, '[20170101,20170101]'::daterange, '[10:30,11:00]'::timerange, 20, 10) ;
```

This insert will fail, because you'd be having a time-range overlap, and the same `desk_id` and `space_id`:

```
INSERT INTO 
    reservations 
    (id, dates, times, desk_id, space_id)
VALUES 
    (3, '[20170101,20170101]'::daterange, '[10:00,11:00]'::timerange, 10, 10) ;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I had to first do a `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;`. 

The reason for using two different fields to represent the date and the time is that the reservation is for certain hours on a range of dates. Think "From 9:00 to 15:00 from Monday to Friday".

If I had just one `datetimes tsrange` then this time range will be a continuum.

Comment: Ok, got it, and makes sense. You have the limitation that you cannot cross the 00:00 boundary. I've cleared the part of my answer that doesn't apply.